# Redirect 301 question mark url

Tags: redirect

i have this URL:

**http://www.website/site/dettaglio_struttura.php?idsoggiorno=3**

and i want redirect to

https://website.it/test/thanks/

i tried with 301 but doesnt work, i've tried also with some mod rewrite but nothing,
can you help me about redirecting this url? :))

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. :) Please specify your question. Do you want to redirect from the webserver itself (e.g. Apache), via server side code (PHP) , from HTML, JavaScript...? -> also tag your question accordingly.
There is a huge number of possibilities. See https://css-tricks.com/redirect-web-page/ for very good compilation. Also if you search on stackoverflow e.g. for "page redirect" you get hundreds of questions already answered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-do-i-make-a-redirect-in-php)